# Instalação e configuração do composer no meu localhost

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, composer

Para usar o composer local eu devo instalar ele na pasta onde se encontram meus projetos? No caso **C:/Users/Eu/Trabalhos**...

E como são vários projetos (sites), para cada um devo ter o *composer.json* certo? Mas e a questão das bibliotecas, por exemplo *phpmailer*, em cada projeto eu devo instalar ele ou basta eu adicionar no *composer.json* do projeto o require? Essa parte tá confusa demais pra mim.

Mais uma dúvida, e ao colocar esse projeto online vai funcionar a questão das bibliotecas ou terei que executar o composer no ambiente online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando windows e tiver feito a instalação pelo instalador é muito provavel que o composer esteja Global e portanto você pode usar em qualquer diretorio da sua maquina, basta que tenha o arquivo composer.json se for linux é mais provavel que vc tenha feito a instalação por terminal e é masi facil escolher entre uma instalação local ou global nesse caso se estiver utilizando instalação local você precisa instalar nos diretorios raiz de cada projeto e no servidor também terá que instalar no diretorio raiz do projeto.
[Veja neste artigo](https://www.phpmaranhao.com.br/tag/instalando-o-composer/) como fazer instalação local e global no linux e windows.

Answer (score 0):

O Seguinte Tutorial [(Clique aqui para acessar)](https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-instalar-e-usar-o-composer/) Responde suas perguntas sobre instalação. cada projeto vai ter seu composer.json com todas as bibliotecas que você usa para o projeto. (Seguindo o exemplo do phpmailer digamos que você tem 3 projetos que usam essa biblioteca, então você precisará fazer o require do phpmailer nos 3 projetos da forma como preferir usar o composer podendo ser `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` ou adicionando a seguinte linha no seu composer.json `"phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"`. E sim, se você quiser manter as dependências do seu projeto sempre atualizadas e principalmente se você estiver utilizando o autoload do Composer você vai precisar ter-lo instalado no seu servidor web.

Comment: No caso, tenho que instalar o composer no meu htdocs local e no meu servidor web instalo na raiz do www?

Comment: Eu fiz outra resposta porque ficou muito comprida.